# angular routerLink with queryParams key from enum

Tags: angular

I have the following component

```
export enum QueryParamsEnum {
    node = 'nodeId'
}

export class Component {    
  key = QueryParamsEnum.node;
}
```

and in the template I would like to use the `key` for the `queryParams`

```
<a [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="{ key: 'value' }">
```

but anytime I try, the navigation will be

`?key=value` instead of `?nodeId=value`

is this achievable using the template?

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

Controller:

```
export enum QueryParamsEnum {
  node = 'nodeId'
}

export class Component {    
  key = QueryParamsEnum.node;
}
```

View:

```
<a [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="{ [key]: 'value' }">
```

Comment: if I do this `[queryParams]="{ [key]: node.uid }"` i get compiler error Parser Error: `Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 30 in [{ [key]: node.uid }]`

Answer (score 0):

You can simple define param as a class field

```
export enum QueryParamsEnum {   node = 'nodeId' }

export class Component {     
    public param = { key: QueryParamsEnum.node; };
}
```

And then just pass it to the routerLink

```
<a [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="param">
```